# React logo not going even after removing and adding new components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am unable to find why the react logo is not going even after I remove it from app.js and If I remove it I get the error module not found.
Here is my app.js code

```
import React from "react";
import Header from "./Components/Header";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is what I see on the browser
[image]

I have added some code in my header component, still, I am not able to see it in my browser. I am unable to find the solution, Please help.

Comment: Any warnings or errors in the terminal? From experience I know that ESLint can prevent rebundling if there are issues with the code unless you set up a .env.development file in your root folder. Also check the browser console to see if you're getting errors there.

Comment: Whats in the header component? Also try saving and then reloading the whole server

Comment: it seems that you didn't provide the correct path to your `Header` component,  try to check the path again

Comment: @Andy there are no errors in the terminal

Comment: @vargaking I have just added some accordion component just to check, whether it works or not.

Comment: @mohammadisam I have added the correct path

Comment: @SaurabhMhaske but does the terminal mention that the code has been rebuilt after you've changed the code?

Answer (score 1):

Removing logo.svg in the src folder will help you to remove the logo from the browser.

Comment: I tried to remove it but I am getting this error Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './logo.svg' in 'E:\React.Js\movies app\movies-app\src'

Comment: Now you will have to remove the import module for logo.svg...can you comment the full error your getting

Comment: Here is the error 
ERROR in ./src/App.js 4:0-30

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './logo.svg' in 'E:\React.Js\movies app\movies-app\src'

And my app.js code is above in the question

Comment: Go to App.js and remove the 4th line which would be something like this -> import {logo} from 'logo.svg'. May be something like this you will find. Remove this line. Wherever you see import 'logo.svg'; or something similar, please remove those lines

Comment: That's what I am trying to say, that I have nothing on line 4 still I am getting this error,
Here is my app.js code
import React from "react";
import Header from "./Components/Header";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
    </>
  );
};

export default App;

Comment: Can you please show me header components code... You might have added logo.svg by mistake.

Comment: These are my imports in header component,

import React from "react";
import Accordion from "@mui/material/Accordion";
import AccordionSummary from "@mui/material/AccordionSummary";
import AccordionDetails from "@mui/material/AccordionDetails";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import ExpandMoreIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore";

Comment: Just remove the header component from App.js and check if still the same error exists? Replace header with some random text. Just to check if error exist in header component by chance

Comment: I did remove the header component, but still, the logo did not go.